# NodejS : Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js

I am quite new to node and am currently encountering an error that seems pretty common: `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client`.

I've read a few threads but cannot wrap my head around this one, here is my code so far:

```
router.get('/:id', (req, res) => User.findAll({
  where     : {
    id: req.params.id,
  },
  attributes    : {
    exclude : ['updatedAt'],
  }
})
.then(user => {
  res.send(user);
  res.sendStatus(200);
})
.catch((err) => console.log(err)));
```

What's wrong here? Any help and advices would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: As far as i know `res.send()` is already sending a 200 response. And if you want to change it you can do `res.status(500).send('Something broke!')` :)

Comment: Thank you very much Halil! That was it :)

Comment: I suggest you to look these stuff on documentation and probably there are ton's of questions like this one tho so search first, create second :) But i'm glad to be help

Answer (score 1):

The real reason behind this problem is that you are using both
res.send(user) and res.sendStatus(200).

The error says: Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client

You already send something to the client (in this case res.send(user)) and you can't send another thing now (in this case res.sendStatus(200)).

Once you do res.send, res.redirect, res.sendStatus, res.render, you should not do add any of these again.

You will get this problem if you are using more than one at the same time. Even if you have something like:

```
for(condition) {
   res.send("1st");
} 
res.send("2nd");
```

You should add return statements in front of them like:

```
for(condition) {
   return res.send("1st");
} 
return res.send("2nd");
```

Also as [@Halil Akar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5020919/halil-%C3%87akar) said that 200 status is always returned with res.send. You can also use res.status(301).send(user) to send data and a status at the same time.

I hope it helps.